# Loading views from XIB's - Safe and/or Recommended?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, custom-view

I am using the following code to load views from an XIB.

```
 init(frame: CGRect, number: Int, sizeDivident:CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        if let nibsView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Controls", owner: self, options: nil) as? [UIView] {
            let nibRoot = nibsView[number]
            self.addSubview(nibRoot)
            nibRoot.frame = frame
        }
```

There is no official documentation or recommendation by Apple for this approach. I have also not found any major resources recommending this.

Is it safe and reliable to use this approach for creating reusable views?
The target is to create custom controls in my project.